Blender 4.2 Rotation Socket broke Geometry Node
Recently I updated my Blender version to 4.2 from the previous 4.0.2 I was running on, though I stumbled upon an issue that broke my previously working node setup.

In this setup I had a shower hose that was constructed from rings, instanced onto points retrieved from a curve. Since the 4.2 version however, due to what I presume is the change in the rotation socket it does not seem to fetch the rotation of the points it is instancing the rings on anymore, making them all remain on their original orientation.

I was wondering if there is a better/new way to tackle this issue?

I have resolved the issue myself, turns out all I had to do was realise the curve using realise instance! :^)
